# Redux: props not changing during onClick of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using react with redux, and I have 2 buttons.

One button's onClick will call a function:

```
onClick = {() => props.myFunction()}
```

`myFunction` will return a value of 100 with key of '`MyProperty`'

My 2nd button simply displays the latest value of `MyProperty`:

```
onClick = {() => alert(props.MyProperty)}
```

I connected both the `myFunction` as well as `MyProperty` to the component. But when I click on the first button, then click on the 2nd button, it shows the initial `MyProperty`, and never the updated '100' value.

`myFunction` returns `{type: "MY_FUNCTION", MyProperty: 100}`

And in my reducer I do:

```
case "MY_FUNCTION":
return {
 MyProperty: action.MyProperty,
 ...state
}
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does `myFunction` actually update the store anywhere?

Comment: Can you provide additional code?

Comment: myFunction returns {type: 'MY_FUNCTION', MyProperty: 100}, and it's mapped in the reducer.

Comment: Can you provide the reducer snippet?

Comment: case "MY_FUNCTION":
return {
 MyProperty: action.MyProperty,
 ...state
}

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the reducer is even called? If the store value is actually updated before clicking button2.
Snippets seem fine. Will need more code to see whats wrong

Comment: Amazingly if I change the order of ...state and MyProperty: action.MyProperty in the reducer code (return ...state first then MyProperty ), now it works! How come ?

Comment: ahhh!!! cause ur overwriting the new MyProperty with what's in the previous state! (Due to the ordering - { MyProperty: action.MyProperty, ...state}) vs  {  ...state, MyProperty: action.MyProperty})

Comment: What do you mean ????

Comment: Does that mean in the reducer, you should always put ...state before the actual content to be returned? How come some reducers have it backwards and still works?

Answer (score 0):

```
state = { x: 1 }

{ x: 2 , ...state } ====> { x: 1 }  // x will never be updated as it gets replaced by what was in the previous state
{ ...state, x: 2  } ====> { x: 2 }
```

"When multiple objects are spread and some properties have same keys, how do the final set of values get calculated? The rule is simple: latter spread property overwrites earlier properties that have the same key." https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/

Comment: You could improve your answer and be more specific about what happens when you spread the state after updating a value

Comment: Does that mean in the reducer, you should always put ...state before the actual content to be returned? How come some reducers have it backwards and still works?

Comment: Updated answer.